# At Great Value Expression

Tags: problem-solving

Hi,

How can I find the greatest value of
$2k\sqrt{(r-k)(r+k))}$ with parameter $r$ such that $(r>k)$?

Comment: What do you mean with "at great value expression"?

Comment: not sure im bulgarian i used google translate

Comment: whats the biggest value that this expression can have depending on r where r> k

Comment: Ah, I see. I do not speak English nativly either. Check the Wikipedia page in Bulgarian, click to the English page, and see the name; that might help.

Comment: i just what to know if: A = 2k*sqrt((r-k)*(r+k))  ; where r is parameter .what is the biggest value of A depending on k

Comment: I have suggested an edit for you. If you made any calculations or efforts to answer this you should put them in the question (click edit). Also check the FAQ and other help texts on the site clicking "help" above. You can Google-translate them to Bulgarian.

Comment: no idea. Im making a program C++ where i need to slove this expression

Comment: This isn't a school excercise. Its hard for my knowadge

Comment: I believe it isn't a school exercise and that you can't do it yourself. But you have to try something. See other questions: the people who ask them don't know the answers, but they try to solve them basing on what they know. When they run out of ideas, they ask. Try putting several values for $r$ and $k$. What do you get? Show what you tried, even if it is wrong.

Comment: can you tell me a theorem that would help me ? :/

Comment: I can try tomorrow, it's over midnight where I live. But I'm sure someone will help you before that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Let us equivalently maximize the **square** of your expression. The square of your expression is equal to 
$$r^4-(r^2-2k^2)^2$$
(we "completed the square").

Comment: by k getting smaller (r2−2k2)2  is getting bigger so A is getting smaller is that a point ?

Comment: The point is that a square is always $\ge 0$, so the maximum is reached when $2k^2=r^2$.

Comment: ye that too , ok ty for help :D